# How do I add a file to my apk files in order to allow it to execute on app start?

Tags: javascript, react-native, apk

I have an apk of my business and I want to add an extra file to it in order for the code to run when the program starts (when I click the app to open). I’m not sure what type of file I should add because it’s kind of tricky to know.

I tried to add code to one of the files to open a file on start but it didn’t work. Can someone tell me what kind of file to add to the decompiled apk files in order for this to work?

Comment: Too broad, not specific enough.

Comment: What’s Inside an APK?  (https://www.trustedreviews.com/explainer/what-is-an-apk-4241564)
An APK is a compressed folder that contains the app’s code, assets, etc. In the folder, you’ll find one or more files along with other folders. Let’s look at a few of those files.  You want to add an executable, config, text file, ... . @Kimimomo succinctly states the issue with the question.